# Service error when creating amazon lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hi I am trying to create a lambda function in amazon lambda. Just trying to follow the python tutorial.

After following all the steps I get a "Service Error" when creating the function.

I found this forum discussing about this [link to the forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233266).
I checked with all the environments but still it gives me the service error. 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYACJ.png)

Is it a configuration issue or a problem with the account ?
I am totally new to aws. Appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: i think its very simple. after wich step you got the error.

Comment: After I click on the "create Function" button. It gives the error.

Comment: please add error screen shot with question

Comment: That does not say more than "Service Error"

Comment: i think , its related with an aws account. please contact with aws support center.

Comment: Have you considered using [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com) to manage your deployment? It dumbs down the process drastically. Here's a [step-by-step tutorial](http://serverless-stack.com?utm_source=stackoverflow.com) on the setup.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, but it disappeared when I selected "Choose an existing role" instead of letting the wizard create a role, under "Lambda function handler and role".  If I create a role manually I can then assign it to the Lambda afterwards.  Maybe that'll help you, too?

Comment: Yes I was having a permission issue. Sorted out from having a role with basic execution permissions attached.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. In my case, I had "Enable active tracing" selected. I tried un-checking that option and it got rid of the error. Maybe I had a permissions problem w/XRay? Who knows; I didn't investigate further.